# I can't seem to generate a simple authorization token in Twilio

Tags: twilio, redcap

What is the easiest way for a tenacious but stupid feeling new Twilio user to generate a simple authroization token so that I can send an API token Twilio from another app (REDCap) which I am using to send a one question SMS survey.

Does the trial account not allow me to generate an authorization token?

How quickly does the authorization token in Twilio expire?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This sounds like something that could be answered by looking at Twilio's FAQ or documentation. Alternatively, your local REDCap administrators might have done this in the past and could help. Look for the big blue 'Contact REDCap Administrator' button in the bottom left of your project pages.

Answer (score 1):

You don't generate your auth token, it's assigned to your account. It should be right in front of you when you first log in to your console.

[image]